# parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I am trying to get a token to some site by using curl. It looks like request is done correctly because I have to wait a bit for response however something is during deserialization because I always got error: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8

This is how script looks like:

```
TOKEN=$(curl --request POST \
--url 'https://${DOMAIN_NAME}/getmy/token' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"grant_type":"password", "username":"${USER_EMAIL}",
"password":"${USER_PASSWORD}",
"audience":"https://localhost:8443/my-composite-service", "scope":"openid
email test:read test:write", "client_id": "${CLIENT_ID}",
"client_secret": "${CLIENT_SECRET}"}' -s | jq -r .access_token)
```

Is it because of jq?

What is more I am sure that env variables are there, even with hard coded values the same error will be thrown.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This means the API is not returning valid JSON.

Comment: Do you really have a newline after `openid`, or did you wrap it when posting here? Please don't do that, we need to see the real code.

Comment: Newlines aren't allowed inside JSON strings.

Comment: All your variables won't expand because they're in single quoted strings.

Comment: Look at the output of your curl command without `-s` and without piping to `jq`, it'll have a bunch of complaints like "could not resolve host", I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

- Do not put everything in one line, make it readable instead.
- Structure your code with functions.
- Do error handling.
- Use Bash's debugging functionality.
- Do not build JSON with string concatenation, use JQ instead, because only JQ quotes JSON data correctly. A password may contain quoting characters.

An example:

```
set -eu
set -x

USER_EMAIL="user@domain.org"
USER_PASSWORD="password"
CLIENT_ID="id"
CLIENT_SECRET="secret"
DOMAIN_NAME="domain.org"

data()
{
  local template='
{
  "grant_type":    "password",
  "username":      $username,
  "password":      $password,
  "audience":      "https://localhost:8443/my-composite-service",
  "scope":         "openid email test:read test:write",
  "client_id":     $client_id,
  "client_secret": $client_secret
}'

  if jq <<<null -c \
        --arg username      "${USER_EMAIL}" \
        --arg password      "${USER_PASSWORD}" \
        --arg client_id     "${CLIENT_ID}" \
        --arg client_secret "${CLIENT_SECRET}" \
        "$template"
  then
    return
  else
    printf "ERROR: Can not format request data." >&2
    exit 1
  fi
}

post()
{
  if curl --request POST \
          --url     'https://${DOMAIN_NAME}/getmy/token' \
          --header  'content-type: application/json' \
          --data    "$1" \
          -s
  then
    return
  else
    printf "ERROR: Can not send post request." >&2
    exit 1
  fi
}

token()
{
  if jq -r .access_token
  then
    return
  else
    printf "ERROR: Can not parse JSON response." >&2
    exit 1
  fi
}

TOKEN="$(post "$(data)" | token)"
```